# googleの更新でSharedArrayBufferが使えなくなったのでAWSのCORSについて教えていただきたいです

Tags: javascript, php, amazon-s3, ffmpeg, cors

javascriptライブラリを使っていたのですがグーグルの更新でSharedArrayBufferが定義されてませんとエラーが出て、最近解決の参考にしてたのURLと近い状態になりました。

[Chrome 92以降のSharedArrayBuffer警告に対するZOZOTOWNが実施した調査と解決策](https://techblog.zozo.com/entry/zozotown-shared-array-buffer)

CORSを以下のように分離させたらJSライブラリが起動しましたが、起動させていたサードパーティ側のAWS S3が読み込まなくなりました。

```
PHP
header('Cross-Origin-Opener-Policy: same-origin');
header('Cross-Origin-Embedder-Policy: require-corp');
```

前述の [参考にした記事](https://techblog.zozo.com/entry/zozotown-shared-array-buffer) には、情報を設定する必要があると思いました。

> サードパーティ側（zozo.jp以外のドメイン側）のHTTPヘッダーにCORS（Cross-Origin Resource Sharing）か、CORP（Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy）のどちらかを付与してもらう必要があります。

教えていただきたいのですが、自分の見解ではAWSのCORS設定に
(CORS（Cross-Origin Resource Sharing）か、CORP（Cross-Origin-Resource-Policy）のどちらかを付与してもらう必要があります。)これを記入すればよいかなと思っています。

```
[
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [
            "*"
        ],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "PUT",
            "POST",
            "DELETE"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "http://localhost"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    },
    {
        "AllowedHeaders": [],
        "AllowedMethods": [
            "GET"
        ],
        "AllowedOrigins": [
            "*"
        ],
        "ExposeHeaders": []
    }
]
```

AWSが理解できてなくてサポートの方頂けたらと思います。よろしくお願いします。